# Hago UPDATE de PHP a MySQL pero no me actualiza y no sé por qué

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy actualizando mi tabla de MySQL en función de si su eam (ID) está en un array:

```
foreach ($resultadoComparaArraysExiste as $key => $value) {
    $sql="UPDATE articulos SET `tipo_articulo`=`EXISTE` WHERE `eam`=".$value; 
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);
    if($resultado){
        echo "El artículo con el valor"." ".($value)." "."actualizó correctamente el valor de su campo tipo_articulo. <br>";
    }else{
        echo "El artículo con el valor"." ".($value)." "."tuvo errores en la actualización de su campo tipo_articulo. <br>";
    }

}
```

El caso es que me está devolviendo el mensaje de error que le tengo puesto, no actualiza y PHP no me devuelve ningún error, más allá del mensaje que he escrito yo. Resumen: que no me actualiza y no tengo ni idea de en qué estoy fallando. ¿Alguna idea? Gracias, saludos.

Comment: Tengo dudas con la consulta primero que nada, puedes realizarla directo en la BBDD ¿?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu codigo anterior pusiste como parametro "ean", no "eam", intenta corregir eso, para luego realizar otra prueba,

```
foreach ($resultadoComparaArraysExiste as $key => $value) {
    $sql="UPDATE articulos SET tipo_articulo = 'EXISTE' WHERE ean =".$value; 
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);
    if($resultado){
        echo "El artículo con el valor"." ".($value)." "."actualizó correctamente el valor de su campo tipo_articulo. <br>";
    }else{
        echo "El artículo con el valor"." ".($value)." "."tuvo errores en la actualización de su campo tipo_articulo. <br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Silvio. Finalmente era esa tontería, no me dí cuenta de la letra n. Muchas gracias :)